# Chrome is reporting GMail has Invalid Server Certificate, how do I find out who's fiddling with my certs?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

Chrome is giving the following warning when ever I try and visit GMail or a bunch of other SSL sites.

```
Invalid Server Certificate
You attempted to reach mail.google.com, but the server presented an invalid certificate.
You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.
```

This is the certificate the Chrome reports as invalid:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I think someone or something (proxy, anti-virus, browser extension) is snooping on my SSL traffic.

How can I determine who/what is doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the latest chrome that a lot of people are having, see here http://www.slashgear.com/google-chrome-hit-by-ssl-bug-restricting-google-services-06221921/

Answer (score 1):

A quick search shows that the certificate that you posted is in fact the correct one. You may have the wrong time, date or any number of other issues that prevent you from realizing this.

Comment: could you elaborate on what the other issues might be?

Comment: You are sure that none of the above apply to you and you don't have some type of malware on your system? Also, does it occur with all browsers?

Comment: Date and time and correct. It appears to be a problem with Chrome only.

Comment: I assume that you have tried restarting chrome?

Answer (score 1):

No Biggie ,

> Just Sync the System date to internet time . or manually set it to
>   correct time

This happens because , the SSL certificate is valid only for a specified period of time , after which your browser renews it regularly . changing the date too ahead or too behind will lead to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the post [Akamai and SSL](http://revealingerrors.com/akamai_ssl), they indicate that a Cache system was involved and it was even caching secure pages, Many ISPs will also use cache systems.  I have no idea if it could apply.
It was obvious in that situation because the location shown in the error.
I suppose you could trace the route, using tracert?  and see where it all goes.

Answer (score 0):

This virus is based on the date. Just change the system's date – either correct it or enter some future date.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a virus. Also, the OP has mentioned their date is set correctly.